# JSP tags vs expression language

Tags: jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

JSP tag below

```
<jsp:useBean id=”employee” class=”employee”/>
<jsp:getProperty name=”employee” property=”name”/>
```

Another used EL

```
{employee.name}
```

Assuming the JSPs compiled properly, how would the 2 pages differ if you had a student object properly populated in the session prior to accessing the page and another when the student object is null.

Can someone explain this to me clearer?

Answer (score 2):

**JSP Tags:**

The [official Sun documentation](http://profesores.elo.utfsm.cl/~agv/elo330/2s03/projects/Tomcat/doc/1.2/syntaxref1217.html) says:

> The `<jsp:useBean>` element locates or instantiates a JavaBeans
>   component.
>
> It first attempts to locate an instance of the
>   bean. If the bean does not exist, `<jsp:useBean>` instantiates it from
>   a class or serialized template.
>
> To locate or instantiate the bean, `<jsp:useBean>` takes the following
>   steps, in this order:
>
> 1. Attempts to locate a bean with the scope and name you specify.
> 2. Defines an object reference variable with the name you specify.
> 3. If it finds the bean, stores a reference to it in the variable. If you specified type, gives the bean that type.
> 4. If it does not find the bean, instantiates it from the class you specify, storing a reference to it in the new variable. If the class
>      name represents a serialized template, the bean is instantiated by
>      java.beans.Beans.instantiate.
> 5. If  has instantiated (rather than located) the bean, and if it has body tags or elements (between  and
>      ), executes the body tags.

The tag will scan in all scopes, in order of `page`, `request`, `session` and `application`:

```
<jsp:useBean id="beanInstanceName" scope="page|request|session|application" ... >
```

**EL:**

It only finds (never creates) attributes in all the same scopes (and same piority order) we have for the beans. Be sure to use [the right EL keywords](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23507_01/Platform.20073/PageDevGuide/html/s0203elvariablescopes01.html) to access them.

---

Getting back to your question, for both strategies, if you have the `student` object set in the scope, both will get it properly as well as handle its attributes.

Otherwise, `useBean` tag would create a new object and store it on the specified scope, while EL would simply print nothing, once it knows when the object is null and doesn't try to access its properties.